# How to call StoredProcedure from JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, stored-procedures, webforms

I have email field and label

```
<asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUserEmail" onfocusout="emailVerification()" CssClass="forTextbox ui-corner-all" PlaceHolder="Enter your email"></asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="smForEmail"></asp:ScriptManager>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upLblEmail">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEmail"></asp:Label>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
```

And some other fields as well.

I want when user move to next field `onfocusout="emailVerification()"` method is called. In this method I want to check either email is exists in database or not. For this I write stored procedure.

```
USE [CDistributors]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_InsertUser]    Script Date: 2/17/2016 2:50:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_InsertUser]
(@Email varchar(50) = null,
@ReturnValue int = null)
As
Begin
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF EXISTS (SELECT UserId from Users where Email = @Email)
Begin

    return 0; -- Email already registered
End 
Else
Begin
    return 1; -- Email is not registered yet
End
End
```

And JavaScript function is

```
// code for email verification
$(function () {
    function emailVerification() {
         // What code to call stored procedure that return integer
    }
});
```

Please help.

Comment: this is very bad idea. You should make server side POST/GET validation  method and ask this method from javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make web service for database call methods it or make it as webmethod on the page

IF you are using .Net Framwork 4 or later you can specify ClientIDMode="Static" for controls to have on client the same Id as you specified

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUserEmail"  ClientIDMode="Static" onfocusout="emailVerification()" CssClass="forTextbox ui-corner-all" PlaceHolder="Enter your email"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here WebMethod call example

```
// code for email verification
$(function () {
    function emailVerification() {
        // What code to call stored procedure that return integer
        var email = $('#txtUserEmail').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'yourPage.aspx/VerifyEmail',
            type: "POST",
            data: "{'email' :' " + email + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
                alert("Maybe you need some stuff before! ");
            },
            success: function (data) { alert(data.d); },
            failure: function (msg) { alert("Something go wrong! "); }
        });
    }
});
```

code behind file

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static int VerifyEmail(string email)
{
    //Your verification code 
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aleksey, its solve my issue. But I make little changes instead of giving `pageName.aspx` I make Web services and it work fine. Else it gives some security error of password fields. Once again thanks.